# "No route to host" when trying to local machine

Tags: ssh

I have a laptop and desktop plugged into the same router via ethernet cable at home.

I can ssh from laptop to desktop, but I cannot ssh from desktop to laptop, I get the error "No route to host"

Port 22 the normal ssh port is open on both machines, ssh is installed on both machines. any ideas?

Comment: Can you provide the output of "ip route" and "ip addr" from each system?

Comment: ssh may be installed on both machines, but what about sshd?

Comment: thanks Wayne, here is output from laptop: https://gist.github.com/sientelo/f28d40125e2d53033fa12751e23e8d17

Comment: and desktop https://gist.github.com/sientelo/a97ac5209673df72b1f38d9f8a6d2765

Comment: I have never heard of sshd user535733  I looked but search engine results are just for ssd